# Modulus after X concatenation

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Given a number $N$ we can form another number $Y$ by concatenating $N$, $X$ times towards right. How to compute $Y \mod \space M$ efficiently?

For example: if $N = 456$ and $X = 3$ then $Y = 456456456$. Now I am wondering how to efficiently compute $Y \mod M$ where $N,M \in \mathbb{N}$.

PS: The motivation of this question comes from [here](http://www.spoj.com/problems/CONCATE/).

Comment: when we are taking about concatenation it's always better to return to the arithmetic expression, I think that if we rewrite $Y$ as $N(10^6+10^3+1)$ may help but still the problem what do you mean exactly by efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Given $N$ with $n$ digits and $x$ a positive integer we have (from your definition):
$$Y=N(10^{nx}+\cdots+10^x+1) $$
so the problem of computing $Y \mod M$ can be reduced to computing $m_1=N\mod M$, computing $n$, compute $m_2=10^{nx}+\cdots+10^x+1 \mod m$, and finally the result is $m_1m_2\mod M $

I hope this answers your question.